# php 7.0 typehint : Fatal error with integer and default value

Tags: php, php-7

I just updated my app to use php7 typehints for scalar types. When i run my unit tests, i got this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type can only be NULL in xxx.php on line 23

The error is in this function :

```
public function call(string $url, integer $timeout = 30)
{
    // some code...
}
```

If i replace `integer` with `int` the error disappears. I always heard that int and integer is the same I don't see anything related to this in the documentation...

The php error seems to say that integer is a class and not a scalar type.

Moreover, `((int) 1) === ((integer) 1)` returns true suggesting again that int and integer are the same

*I use php 7.0.8*

Comment: `integer` isn't documented at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.  I would argue they shouldn't have allowed `(integer)` in type casting to avoid confusion like this.

Comment: so i suppose it will be the same for `bool` and `boolean`

Comment: I would assume so.  The actual keywords are bool and int in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php

Comment: I spent ½ hour figuring out I had typeHinted `boolean` instead of `bool` making PHP thinking some class «boolean» should be loaded in the current namespace.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the documentation these are the valid types:

```
Class name
Interface name
self
array
callable
bool
float
int
string
```

Also there's this:

> Warning
>
> Aliases for the above scalar types are not supported. Instead, they
>   are treated as class or interface names. For example, using boolean as
>   a parameter or return type will require an argument or return value
>   that is an instanceof the class or interface boolean, rather than of
>   type bool.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: I missed that in the doc... it is not written in the "new features" page